# Фильтрация товаров на сайте на Битриксе

Tags: битрикс, фильтрация

Есть вопрос по фильтрации товаров в каталоге на сайте. Работы ведутся на сайте: https://textileavenue.ru/catalog/. Сейчас фильтрация происходит моментально при выборе любого пункта (меняется количество товаров и меняется URL). Есть проблема с генерацией URL, который попадает в индекс поисковых систем и сайт понижается в ранжировании.
Есть идея сделать таким образом, чтобы фильтрация работала без подмены URL. Нормально ли это будет и не возникнет ли никаких проблем? Может есть какие-то более хорошие решения? Спасибо.

Comment: Сейчас не до конца понятен вопрос. Вы имеете ввиду сделать так, чтоб не происходило физической перезагрузки страницы (перехода на новый адрес), но фильтрация при этом срабатывала?

Comment: С точки зрения именно адресации, если планируется seo-продвижение по страницам с конкретными параметрами фильтрации, то адреса нужно оставить. А еще лучше копать в сторону ЧПУ для фильтров